# How to resize text based on screen size in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I am developing an app on Flutter, I have a Column which contains two Text Widgets in my Home Page. the problem is that on a mobile phone, the text size is normal, but on a tablet, the text is way too small to see. Could you please suggest a way to enlarge the text dynamically based on the screen size?

The Widget:

```
Column(
    children: [
      Text(
        widget.label,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      Text(
        widget.description,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package here :

`auto_size_text` , https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text

Would help.

Answer (score 0):

you can have two approaches:

1. use `auto_size_text` package
2. use  `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` and `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` to access width and height of screen, then use them to resize a `SizedBox` and pass your text as a `FittedBox(child:YourTextWidget)` to this widget. for example:

```
SizedBox(
width: 0.5 * screenWidth, // change 0.5 to whatever your want
child:FittedBox(
child: Text("Your Text")
))
```